# Could not open X display giggle: Cannot open display

Tags: xserver

I'm completely new to Linux, I have installed in my computer (running on windows 7) a Virtual machine with Ubuntu desktop 14.04. I have installed some programs using `apt-get install NAME_OF_THE PROGRAM`. The problem is that when I try to launch the GUI of these programs from a terminal, I'm always getting problems and I don't get to have the programs working. Now I have installed Giggle, the installation was ok but if I try to run `giggle` from the terminal I get:

```
** (giggle:8581): WARNING **: Could not open X display giggle: Cannot open display:
```

And this problem is for all the programs that I install.

For example if I try to run `xhost` I get:

```
xhost: unable to open display "localhost:0"
```

What is the next step to fix these problems??

Any help or recommendation would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following command from your terminal to fix this:

```
sudo service lightdm start
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

LightDM is the display manager running in Ubuntu, the first command starts this service. The second command sets the value in `DISPLAY` variable for exporting display on the client.

Comment: Great!! It is working now! Could I have a little explanation of what was happening just to learn it and avoid problems in the future? Thanks!!

Comment: LightDM is the display manager running in Ubuntu , the first command starts this service. The second command sets the value in DISPLAY variable for exporting display on the client.
I would appreciate if you could upvote/ mark this answer as accepted.